# debugging a very simple python code and saw the unexpected result, just want to know why is it happening

Tags: python-3.x, debugging

```py
def fun_test(count):
    print(count)
    if count > 1:
        fun_test(count - 1)

fun_test(5)
```

I played with this straightforward python code today, and when I follow the debugger, I noticed the following.

On the debugger, the `count` starts to decrease as I expected it `5, 4, 3, 2, 1` then I was expecting the function to end. but the execution continued and suddenly `count` jumps `2, 3, 4, and 5` then `name 'count' is not defined.`

Why is that happening?

Comment: I misspelled the function name when I rewrote it here, and I will fix it right away. And when I put the beak point at `print(count)`, it starts at `2` and counts up until `5`.

Comment: Great observation and I'm glad you asked about it. Thanks for fixing the code and the observation regarding the debugging values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me put some line numbers on your code, so we can discuss it:

```
1  def fun_test(count):
2     print(count)
3     if count > 1:
4         fun_test(count - 1)
5  
6  fun_test(5)
```

And let's assume a breakpoint in line 2, right before the `print()` statement.

I'll use the "Step over" debugger command, indicated by this button or <kbd>F8</kbd>:

[image: Step over]

You'll need a rough understanding of a stack. The stack was designed exactly for functions and local variables. It is a region memory which grows in one direction. It will grow whenever you call a function and it will shrink whenever the function ends. For the sake of simplicity, let me say it stores the following:

- the line number where to continue running when the function ends
- some information about the method that is currently running
- the local variables

This is technically not very correct, but sufficient for explaining what happend in your debugging session.

A different concept would be a "heap", where content is filled more or less randomly.

So what will happen?

- Python reads the file (lines 1 to 5) and defines a function called `fun_test()`.
- Python reads line 6 and knows that the function `fun_test()` with an argument of `5` shall be called.
- In order to know where to continue after the function call, it will put a `6` (current line) onto the stack.
- It puts the name of the function onto the stack, that's `fun_test`
- It puts the arguments on the stack, which is `5`
- Now Python calls the function and can access the number `5` as if it were a local variable.
- You break at the breakpoint and can see `count` being `5`.

[image: Debugger in line 2]

- You step forward until line 4.
- Python knows that the function `fun_test()` with an argument of `4` (`count-1`) shall be called.
- The same process repeats:

  - In order to know where to continue after the function call, it will put a `4` (current line) onto the stack.
  - It puts the name of the function onto the stack, that's `fun_test`
  - It puts the argument on the stack, which is `4`
- Now Python calls the function and can access the number `4` as if it were a local variable.
- You break at the breakpoint and can see `count`being `4`.

[image: Debugger in line 2, second call]

However, note the following:

- the stack size has increased. In the "Frames" part, you can see all the functions that have been called. The debugger knows how Python maintains the stack and decodes that information for you.
- You can also see all the line numbers that have been copied to the stack. At the very beginning, we come from line 6. The we came from `fun_test` in line 4 and currently you're at `fun_test` again, but in line 2.

[image: Frames]

Also note: initially, the argument 5 has been passed to the function. That 5 was copied onto the stack and has not been removed yet. You can prove that by clicking the middle function. On the right side, see that this "instance" of the function still thinks `count` is `5`.

[image: Frames revisited]

The same process continues for 3, 2 and 1 and each method will have its own idea of what `count` is:

[image: all frames]

When you step forward now, things become interesting again. When `count` is `1`, the condition `count > 1`no longer holds and the function ends. In that case, the procedure is reversed:

- the argument `1` is no longer needed, so it can be removed from the stack
- the name of the function is no longer needed, so it can be removed from the stack
- the line number of the previous function is taken from the stack as well
- Python restores the line number, so it can continue where it left

And, voilá, we're back at `fun_test` at the end of line 4. That function thought `count` is 2 and still thinks so, because that number is still on the stack.

[image: Back in time]

That method ends as well, so

- the argument `2` is no longer needed and removed
- the name of the function is removed
- the line number is restored

And the program is back in a function where the number 3 is still on the stack.

[image: Yet another stack thing]

And so on, until it reaches line 6 where it started and the whole prgram ends.

The whole procedure is totally normal and very similar in other programming languages as well, e.g. C#, Java and C++.

Your experiment can even be a little more exciting with this code:

```
def fun_test(count):
    print(count)
    if count > 1:
        fun_test(count - 1)
    print(count)  # What do you expect to be printed here?

fun_test(5)
```

Have fun debugging! It's totally worth learning and understanding. If you master it, you'll be much more successful in tackling down bugs.

Comment: First of all, Thank you so much for the detailed and clear explanation.  the addition of the screenshot is even amazing. since I use VS Code I don't have the *Fream* windows (or I don't know how to configure it yet). but after your explanation, I totally understood the Call stack even if it doest shows me the values. and it was mind-blowing to see the code you provided. I totally didn't expect that will be the output. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Hanoch: I'm glad it was helpful. I used JetBrains PyCharm Community Edition. It's free as well. I'm not familiar with Python and VS Code, but I would hope that it has the local variables somewhere.

Comment: @Hanoch VS Code has "Call Stack" instead of "Frames" and it has "Variables" as well. They will change as you click a function in the call stack. https://i.stack.imgur.com/noH9y.png

Comment: VS Code does have *variables, watch, and call stack* windows. Thanks to you now I know how to use call stack (like FREAM in PyCharm). Thank you for giving me your time and helping me out. I'm amazed at how detailed your answer is. Danke schön  --Edit, I didn't saw your second comment. I was searching for Danke schön :)